# Mongodb Replication Set Server Status: What does FATAL status actually mean?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo db replication set with three servers. The 3rd node shows that it is in a FATAL status:

```
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "slave2-1:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 4,
        "stateStr" : "FATAL",
        "uptime" : 276,
        "optime" : {
            "t" : 1321929689000,
            "i" : 1
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2011-11-22T02:41:29Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2011-11-22T02:46:05Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0
}
```

When I log into the server in question, the mongo shell prompt shows that it is in fatal status. What does the FATAL status actually mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: I was able to remove the node and add it back, now it works. I would still like to know what causes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fatal state means that the member is in some state that it cannot recover from.  You will need to intervene to get it back online.  You should shut it down and diagnose the issue (if you don't know why it's in fatal state, there should be information about it in its log).

Common causes of fatal state are an invalid config, removing a node from the set (prior to 2.0), a failed rollback, or any other unhandled exceptional situation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have to say something here.. Fatal states does not mean that the member is in some state that it cannot recover from. It could mean that the current elected primary is in a totally different state than the current Fatal state node. Which code be fixed if you make the current fatal become the primary in anyway. I could do that by replicating the fatal state node dbpath with the current elected primary node and then all members started syncing again. The fatal state does not mean you have any damaged or corrupted data at all!